# Start external program, but keep application in foreground

Tags: java, firefox

I'm writing an RSS reader desktop application in Java with Swing (odd choice, I know) that needs to start the web browser of the user's choice (suppose it's Firefox). I use runtime.exec("firefox -new-window $url"). This starts a new window of Firefox which appears in the foreground.

When I click a link in the application, I want to start Firefox but keep my application on the top (so I can open several links and then go back to them). Is there a way to do this? Preferably it should work with any browser (any program) and start it maximized but not in the foreground, though I'd settle for other solutions like starting minimized or using some command line arguments of Firefox (I haven't found any for this purpose).

It's kind of funny - all the questions about this I've found is people having the opposite problem, and also I've written a similar application several years back in C# which works as intended. I vaguely remember having the same problem, but looking at the sources now, I don't see what was the solution - it seems like it simply starts the browser with no extra stuff.

Comment: Isn't `Desktop.open()` the modern way to open an browser?

Comment: Doesn't that only start the default browser? Maybe I could live with that, but what if I want to pass parameters like the mentioned -new-window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The reason why I could not find the right answer was that I was asking the wrong question. The solution has actually nothing to do with launching programs. All that is necessary is to set `.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` on the main JFrame.